# kill process, throw an event and catch it whithin winform application

Tags: winforms, kill-process

I've some Winform App which controls over some COMobject (start record and stop record)
When I'm launching the winform app, I actually start recording by uisng COMobject.

The problem is how to stop the record (closing Winform app where on close event I'll stop record).
So how do I fire this event ? I was thinking to kill the WinForm app, but it seems not to be working...

any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Have u tried overriding Application_Exit event ?

Comment: You say you've tried the close event, have you tried the FormClosed event?